# How to install applet on smart card using java

Tags: java, applet, smartcard, javacard, apdu

Is there any way to load .**cap**(converted applet) design in java card in to java and then install applet from that .cap(converted applet) file into smart card?
I am having .cap file that is converted applet file and i want to install applet present in that .cap file.
First tell me how to load .cap file in java.
In java i am using **javax.smartcardio** package to interact with smart card and apdu commands to interact with applet installed in smart card.
I am using:

1. smart card type = contact card
2. using **JavaCard2.2.2** with **jcop** using **apdu**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On every programmable JavaCard there is a pre-loaded applet called "CardManager". This applet has to be used for uploading and installing new applets.

In most cases the used SDK of your JavaCard comes with libraries that encapsulate the necessary steps for selecting the CardManager (including necessary authentication), loading and installing an applet. It bases on the install and load commands defined in the [GlobalPlatform](http://globalplatform.org) standard.

The necessary steps/commands are for example explained here: [Installing JavaCard Applet into real SmartCard](http://adywicaksono.wordpress.com/2008/01/05/installing-javacard-applet-into-real-smartcard/). However the concrete authentication sequence (CardManager AID, used authentication key) for your card depends on what card type you have.

Comment: What is the difference between Card Manager and Security Domain?